# Grails : start the application without connecting to database

Tags: database, grails, jdbc

I have an application in grails, which i can the change the parameters in the welcome page, database configuration included (server, username, ...), i externalized the db configuration from the datasource so i can change it.
What i want to do, is to have the possibility to start the application without any database configured, so i can configure it after that, in the welcome page.
Is this possible with grails ? i want at least load the first page (this page doesn't retrieve any information from the db).

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343967/can-i-configure-grails-with-no-datasource

Comment: i have a database to work with after loading the index page, it's not the same problem i think !

Answer (score 2):

I did a blog post along these lines a while back: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=312

I'm not sure if it still works with 2.0, but it shouldn't require too much tweaking. By delaying the creation of the datasource, you can configure the connection properties of the DataSource bean or in the Grails config and after that the next connection request will use the new configuration.

Comment: I have been trying to follow those examples in Grails 3.2.3. Go figure. No success at all.

Comment: I spent a while trying to update the code for Grails 3 and recent versions of GORM but there have been a lot of changes and I found multiple blocking issues and I wasn't able to get this working