# Grails : change the current environment

Tags: grails, datasource, environment

is it possible to change the current working environment on runtime ??
what i want to do, is to load my application on a specific environment, and change it after somewhere in the code, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a reasonable extent no. This would likely confuse the framework greatly and is not recommended.

Comment: ah ok, what i want to do, is to change the working database at runtime, is there another way to do it ??

Comment: If you know your datasource before starting the app, and simply need to switch your domain classes from one to the other during runtime, check the multiple datasource feature from the documentation: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.RC1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

Comment: As the above answer says, it is not recommended, and possibly you will run into issues. Can you give more details about what you are trying to achieve, you may get a better solution.

Comment: Lauri : thanks

sudhir : check my other post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225187/grails-start-the-application-without-connecting-to-database

my idea is to create two environments, one with hdb to load the apllication, then switch to another environment with my db configured in the application.