# Grails without gorm

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create a grails app that has no database/hibernate/gorm/datasource configuration.  In Rails, I can create a new app with the '--skip-active-record' command which will let me create controllers/models/etc without any database concerns.

I'm needing this because my controller just makes a couple rest calls and returns a result so there's no need for the database.

Is this possible?  I saw [Can I configure Grails with no datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343967/can-i-configure-grails-with-no-datasource) but it seems to not work with Grails 2.3.  I get this message: "To remove a plugin, delete it from BuildConfig.groovy and/or application.properties."

Is this possible?  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The `uninstall-plugin` and `install-plugin` commands were deprecated in 2.2 and removed in 2.3.

To remove a plugin, delete it from `BuildConfig.groovy` and/or `application.properties`.

So you can just remove the `hibernate` plugin entry from `BuildConfig.groovy`. You probably also need to remove the `cache` plugin, and you should remove the `database-migration` plugin since you won't need it.